useContext, typescript. What am I not getting here?
So I have been doodling with react and typescript for a bit.
Initially working with javascript, but now trying to explore typescript.
I had a ok grasp on useContext in js, with simple a simple boolean state.
But I cant figure out what I'm missing in this typescript implementation.
My context code
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export interface UserStateInterface{
  loggedinIn: boolean;
  userid: number;
  username: string;
}

type StateContextType = {
  user: UserStateInterface;
  setUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserStateInterface>>;
};

export const StateContext = createContext<StateContextType>(
  null as unknown as StateContextType,
);

type ContextProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }: ContextProviderProps) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    
  loggedinIn: false,
  userid: 0,
  username: "string",
});


  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

Where its implemented.
<StateContext.Provider value={{user: {userid:0, username: "", loggedinIn: false}, setUser() }}>
        <Header />
        <TabNav />
        </StateContext.Provider>

Intially I thought, it would take an object of the userstate, but thats wrong. setUser, is also not ok cause its calling a function that returns void. Maybe theres a better, way to solve this, where the state is never null, but I'm sure I'd benefit from fully understanding this.
I have tried pass different values to value prop

ContextProvider is different to StateContext.Provider. Are you intending to pass the initial value for the state?

"Initially working with javascript" then you can provide type annotations for your working js

"Where its implemented"... is meant to use <ContextProvider>

What about this?
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export interface UserStateInterface {
  loggedIn: boolean;
  userId: number;
  username: string;
}

type StateContextType = {
  user: UserStateInterface;
  setUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserStateInterface>>;
};

const initialUser: UserStateInterface = {
  loggedIn: false,
  userId: 0,
  username: "",
};

const initialStateContextValue: StateContextType = {
  user: initialUser,
  setUser: () => {},
};

export const StateContext = createContext<StateContextType>(
  initialStateContextValue
);

type ContextProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }: ContextProviderProps) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserStateInterface>(initialUser);

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};



This just changes the context value from an object to an array. Why would that be better?

I won't say better. Just it's typed. You can have it as an object like orginal is

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
